# Is is possible to show removable drives on Plank?

Tags: plank

I would like to have removable drives show up on the dock every time one is plugged in. Is this possible?

Maybe a udev rule could do this if it is not a feature of Plank?

Comment: As far as I know, plank only comes with the default docklets. The only other I have been able to find was a CPU monitor [here](https://github.com/ricotz/plank/tree/master/docklets).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend installing Docky instead of Plank ([https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203803/replace-plank-with-docky-in-elementary-os)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203803/replace-plank-with-docky-in-elementary-os). And then enabling the "Mounter" docklet to show what drives are mounted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I prefer not to use Docky, personally. Maybe this may help someone else though so I will still upvote.