# Can I install a places status indicator like Ubuntu's?

Tags: release-juno

For the top panel or Plank - a places list that shows devices as well as folders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the panel, but as far as Plank is concerned, no, I don't think so. Someone else suggested swapping Plank for Docky [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/is-is-possible-to-show-removable-drives-on-plank), but I don't think that's a great solution either since I don't believe Docky is being maintained or actively developed for anymore (their last release was back in 2015, not necessarily a bad thing but a reddish flag).

Comment: I can drag and drop a folder onto Plank, which is nearly there. Can't get rid of it though as right-click just opens the folder.

Comment: Right click opens the folder but there is also a checkbox **keep in Dock** and if you uncheck it - the folder disappears.